# How to include Redoc in React app?

Tags: reactjs, swagger-ui

I am writing an api portal using react and want to include Redoc (https://github.com/Rebilly/ReDoc) in the react component. Is it possible to use Redoc in react application? If yes, then what is the best way to do this.

I've tried initializing ReDoc via globally exposed Redoc object but it throws esprima and jquery missing error. I've installed these packages but still no luck.

```
import {Redoc} from './redoc';
module.exports = Redoc;

Redoc.init('http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json', {
  scrollYOffset: 50
})
```

Also, if I include in the component directly

```
render() {
   return(
     <div>
       <redoc spec-url='http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json'>
       </redoc>
    </div>
  ); 
}
```

it throws "Unknown prop `spec-url` on  tag" error.

Answer (score 1):

ReDoc is being rewritten to use React.  When this pull request is completed, and merged, you would be able to easily include ReDoc in your React application.

https://github.com/Rebilly/ReDoc/pull/357